# CSS - Maintain page height

Tags: html, css, height

I am trying to keep header of the page at top and footer at the bottom. If the container grows, the footer should be pushed down.

I have following working code using `calc()`, but all browsers don't support it. So, I need alternative for this. Please note, I want CSS only solution.

**Code:**

```
header{
    height:50px;
    background:#CCC;
}
footer{
    height:30px;
    background:#333;
}
main{
    height:auto;
    min-height:calc(100% - 80px);
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/g3r7xdm3/)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: footer always on bottom? try with position absolute with bottom 0 and left 0

Comment: @Cheshire it will not work if container grows

Comment: @Hiral What do you exactly mean? With if the container grows?

Comment: also, try with position:fixed and left and bottom to 0

Comment: @MLeFevre it works perfectly!!! please post answer so that I can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set your main content to a `min-height` of 100%, with a negative margin the **same height** as your footer, for example (cribbed from http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    color:#FFF;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important; /* This line and the next line are not necessary unless you need IE6 support */
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -155px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
footer, .push {
    height: 155px;
}


<div class="wrapper">
    <header>Header</header>
    Main Content
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u6rsLv1j/2/

Comment: add a pusher element before footer, also header should be inside wrapper, otherwise, some of the height will be cut.. add text and check

Comment: @Hiral yep you're right, missed that bit whilst copying & pasting

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
header{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:50px;
    background:#CCC;
}
footer{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    height:30px;
    background:#333;
}
main{
    height:auto;
    margin:50px 0 30px;
}
```

This way, your header and footer would always stay on the very top and the very bottom, just the content of your "main"-container seems to be scrollable. Not very sure about this is what you searched for...

Comment: footer should be pushed when content grows. it is not happening with this code.

Comment: then, @Roman Bosski 's solution is your way to go. Didn't get that right, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the position absolute to footer and the position relative to his parent as in code below.
Position fixed is not a good solution in this case because bottom:0 in position fixed means the bottom of the first screen, so it wont scroll with the page. Not mentioning it has serious problems f.ex. on mobile devices.

EDIT: Try to run below code snippet in new window, as the preview isn't rendered properly.

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
html,body{height:100%;width:100%; position:relative;}
header{height:50px;background:#CCC;}
footer{height:30px;width:100%;background:#333; position:absolute; bottom:0;}
/*main{height:auto;min-height:calc(100% - 80px);}*/
p{padding-top:5px;}
p:last-of-type{padding-bottom:5px;}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Try it with more hello paragraphs and scroll down

Comment: it does not work when content is very long.. thanks for your efforts though

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use min-height and position absolute within relative.
Here you go:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }


.page-wrapper{
    position:relative;
    min-height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.header{
    height:50px;
    background:#CCC;
}
.footer{
    background:#333;
    height:30px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
}
.main{

}
    </style>
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <div class='header'>header</div>
        <div class='main'>main</div>
        <div class='footer'>footer</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is total solution of your problem.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/