# How to get the sticky footer to work?

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky, sticky-footer

I'm trying to figure out how to get the footer to stick to the bottom of the page in the css of http://bit.ly/138xOAB

I've tried alot of things which were said in tutorials, such as:

- the position absolute,
- bottom:0,
- and min-height of the container 100%,
- height of the body 100%,

But none of those things turned out well.

You can see the HTML and CSS by inspecting the website. I can't get the proper code over here.

Can someone help me, maybe there is something wrong in the HTML?

Comment: `You can see the HTML and CSS by inspecting the website. I can't get the proper code over here.` You can always copy the relevant code from the element inspector. Or right click->view source..

Comment: There are so many [sticky footer posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417878/css-maintain-page-height/27418284) out there...

Comment: remove position:absolute from your footer. Or if you want footer to be shown all the time, then use position:fixed and appropriate margins/paddings as for your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with you footer's `position: absolute;` is that it will hide the other elements behind it.

Your footer can be best viewed if you remove `position: absolute;` so as to show all elements and add `margin-top: 20px;` for some gap in between the footer and the element before it..

Try it.

**EDIT:**

If you want the footer to be always float on the screen, use the following CSS (*comments inline*):

```
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px 3%;
  margin-bottom: 250px; /* so that all content is visible */
}

.footer {
  background: #efefef;
  position: fixed; /* so that the footer floats */
  overflow: auto;
  bottom: 0px; /* float at bottom */
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  height: 180px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd tried but it still wont float at the bottom after the content.

Comment: @HugOnline Please see the **EDIT** in my answer above.

Comment: Thanks Rahul for your help! The thing is, I want it to be at the bottom of the page, not the bottom of the screen. Can u please help me with that?

Comment: @HugOnline My first solution was for that only. :)

Comment: @HugOnline Let me know if you have any more questions. If you think this answer has solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "position: absolute" and "bottom: 0" from the .footer class. I think that fixes your issue. And add a small margin above the footer so there is a small space between the content and the footer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but when you take a look at another page, registration for example, you see the footer floating instead of pushed down.